# how to replace the elements using simple_html_dom

Tags: php

I'm using simple_html_dom to parsing the elements..

Here is the output:

```
<span id="time1">4:00 PM </span> - <span id="title1">The Real Housewives of New York City"If You Can Make It Here"</span><br><br><span id="time2">5:00 PM </span> - <span id="title2">The Real Housewives of New York City: Give Up the Ghostwriter:    </span><br><br>
```

Here is the current PHP:

```
<?php
$errmsg_arr = array();
$errflag = false;
$link;
include ('simple_html_dom.php');

function db_connect()
{
  define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
  define('DB_USER', 'myusername');
  define('DB_PASSWORD', 'mypassword');
  define('DB_DATABASE', 'mydbname');

  $errmsg_arr = array();
  $errflag = false;
  $link = mysql_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

  if(!$link) 
  {
    die('Failed to connect to server: ' . mysql_error());
  }

  $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE);
  if(!$db) 
  {
    die("Unable to select database");
  }
}

    $links = $row['links'];
    $html = file_get_html($links);
    //echo $row['links'];

    $base = $row['links'];

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $base);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $base);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $str = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    $html = new simple_html_dom();
    // Load HTML from a string
    $html->load($str);

    //get all category links
    /*foreach($html_base->find('a') as $element) {
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r( $element->href );
        echo "</pre>";
    }*/

    //$html_base->clear();
    //unset($html_base);

    $time1 = $html->find('span[id=row1Time]', 0)->plaintext;
    $title1 = $html->find('li[id=row1-1]', 0)->plaintext; // with this
    $output1 = preg_replace('/\d:\d+/', '', $title1);

    $html->clear();
    unset($html);


    echo '<span id="time1">'.$time1.'</span> - ';

    if (strstr($output1, '"'))
    {
      $output1 = str_replace('"', ':', $output1);
    }
?>
```

I have tried this:

```
$output1 = str_replace('"', ':', $output1);
```

It will replace the double quotes with ":". I only want to replace the single quote between on the two texts.

Example:

```
The Real Housewives of New York City"If You Can Make It Here"
```

As you can see I want to replace the single quote between the text City and If. I want to make it looks like this:

```
The Real Housewives of New York City: If You Can Make It Here
```

When I tried this:

```
$output1 = str_replace('"', ':', $output1);
```

I will get something like this:

```
The Real Housewives of New York City: If You Can Make It Here:
```

Can you please tell me how I can check on the elements if they have the single quote in the middle of the text even I don't want to replace the single quote at the end of the element?

And how I can replace the text at the end of the element to replace the single quote with a empty text?

Edit: Here is the output:

```
                         PM                                                                                                                                                                                                       The Real Housewives of Beverly Hills                                                                                               : Reunion Part 3"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                TV-14                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            &nbsp;(D,L)                                                                                                                                                                                                        <span id="time1">7:00 PM </span> -
```

Comment: You can pass in a limit: `str_replace('"', ':', $output1, 1)`, then afterwards run it again to get rid of the end quote: `str_replace('"', '', $output1, 1)`

Comment: @scrowler thanks for this, I have tried to use what you just said but it did not work as i will get an empty output without the error. could you please post the correct source that I should use?

Comment: Basic stuff mate: `$output1 = str_replace('"', ':', $output1, 1); $output1 = str_replace('"', '', $output1, 1);`

Comment: @scrowler i have tried it but it don't work. I have only got is the empty page. There is no error in my php page, so i'm not sure what's wrong?

Comment: Empty page means you've got a parse error or a syntax error which your server is not showing you. You should always turn up your error reporting levels to the highest possible on your local or development servers to catch these errors. Put this at the top of your PHP script: `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @scrowler I have edited the php.ini and I found the error, here it is: Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference in /home/myusername/public_html/myscript.php on line 159

Comment: ............ and line 159 is?

Comment: $output1 = str_replace('"', ':', $output1, 1);

Comment: My mistake, it's an output variable not an input variable. Try this instead: `$output1 = preg_replace('/"/', ':', $output1, 1);`

Comment: @scrowler I have tried but it don't work, it won't replace the text. The return for the output is ` The Real Housewives of New York City"Model Behavior"`. Any idea?

Comment: It's working for me: https://eval.in/130375

Comment: I can see it is working for me too. The output is: `The Real Housewives of Beverly Hills                                                                                               : Reunion Part 3"`, can you tell me how I can remove the long space next to the ":" to make it come together like `The Real Housewives of Beverly Hills: Reunion Part 3`?

Comment: Please see on my first post that I have edited.

Comment: @scrowler did you see my first post?

Comment: I suggest you browse the PHP manual. Look up `trim()`, `explode()`, `str_replace()` and `preg_replace()`